# How to install, test, and run WCF on a windows 8 tablet pc?

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, wcf, xaml, windows-8.1

I am a noobie, but trying to understand how to put these pieces together. I am getting very confused on the terminology being used so Google is just adding to my confusion.

In short, I have three projects:
Project #1: is a data source using an EntityFramework that connects to my local database server.
Project #2: is a WCF Service Application that addresses the EntityFramework.
Project #3: is a WPF client Application that consumes the WCF services.

All the above works well on my development machine with visual studio 2010 and windows 7.

I used ClickOnce to publish the above solution and copied the resulting files to a windows 8 tablet. After using the setup.exe provided by clickonce, it appears that the application (the WPF Client) can no longer connect to the WCF Service Application (or the WCF service application is not running).

So, my question is:
1. On the Windows 8 tablet, how do I test to see if IIS is installed and/or running ?
2. How do I verify that the WCF Service application is installed and/or running ?
3. How can I verify the endpoints on the WCF Service application on the tablet pc?

(The term "hosting" is confusing since the development machine "hosts" the WCF. But I can't figure out how to setup the windows 8 tablet pc to "host" the WCF when clickonce installed it.) Anybody have some simple instructions?

Thanks for any help understanding this.

Comment: I would expect a table to only use the client portion of your solution, and the remainder of the solution (WCF service and EF repository) would be on a *server*, not a tablet.  What kind of tablet is it (is it running RT or the full kernel)?

Comment: @Tim I am confused. The database server is running PostgreSQL. The development machine, my laptop, has all three projects in the single solution and addresses the server without difficulty. I copied all the published folder from the laptop to the tablet pc and ran setup.exe on the tablet. Is this not correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Tim The tablet is a Samsung running the full version of windows 8.1

Comment: What I mean is that it strikes me as an unusual scenario where a mobile device (tablet, phone, whatever) is hosting a WCF service.  I would expect the WCF service to remain on a server somewhere and the client to be on the tablet.  I can't think of any use cases off the top of my head (outside of just trying to see it it could be done) for putting a WCF (or any webservice) on a mobile device.

Comment: @Tim My client is a WPF application that references the WCF project of the same solution. How would the WPF application connect to the WCF service when they are not on the same machine?

Comment: WCF (web services) are designed to be used by remote machines.  You can certainly consume a WCF service that is on the same machine as a client, but that is not a normal use case.  If you had a service on a server, for example, and wanted the tablet to consume it (as a client), you would simply give the client the address of the server where the service is and connect that way.

Comment: @Tim Ok (??). Assuming the client and the service are on the same machine, how does one assign the .svc to a specific port, say localhost:1234 ? Or even better, can ClickOnce perform port assignment through its setup.exe application? Many thanks on this.

Comment: @Tim Somewhat related question. Where does the WCF Service Application get its port number from?